# Seasonal Loan Amortization

Tags: loans, calculation, amortization

Hi I can compute a Basic Loan Amortization Schedule, But now I'm trying to Calculate a Seasonal Loan Amortization Schedule . So for example A loan starts at January And Will go on for `3 years`, with `Monthly Payments`. Interest is at `3% Annually and is compounded Annually`. During the months of `September, October, November, December` It'll only `accumulate Interest` But no payments and principal. `Principal is 100000`. How Do I calculate Payments and interest.

Comment: Is this homework? What country are you in? I don't claim to know everything, but I've never heard of such a loan.

Comment: Not my Homework, A question I made off the top of my head. And It's in Canada. Some loan companies do give off seasonal loans.  <http://www.hemafinance.com/en/calculators/loan/15/seasonal-loan-calculator> A calculator is already Made for a type of question like this, so It's not common but it's also not uncommon. Dont mind the double negatives. Just trying to portray a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the payments as shown below. But first a basic monthly payment calculation to show the method :-

```
s = 100000
t = 3
n = 12
i = 0.03
```

The basic case using the formula [here](http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html) :-

This formula needs the periodic rate, `r`

```
r = (1 + i)^(1/n) - 1

monthly payment = (r*s)/(1 - (1 + r)^(-(n*t)))
```

> 2906.34

Now the same calculation using a more complicated formula given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate#European_Union) :-

In the formula each `a(1 + i)^(-k/n)` term is a payment.  Solving gives the monthly payment ,`a`, as demonstrated earlier.

[image]

By omitting payments for September, October, November & December, (since `a` for these dates is zero), solving finds the payment amount for the remaining 24 months.

[image]

So to repay the loan in 24 equal payments each payment should be 4338.17.

The interest remains 3% annually.

(This method uses [EU APR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate#European_Union), so you may need to convert your rate first.)

**Edit**

Taking another go to match the output of the [Hema calculator](http://www.hemafinance.com/en/calculators/loan/15/seasonal-loan-calculator).

Here is the output to be matched :-

[image]

First a simple longhand calculation, solved using *Mathematica* :-

```
r = 0.03/12;

p[0] = 100000;
p[1] = p[0] - (a - r p[0]);
p[2] = p[1] - (a - r p[1]);
p[3] = p[2] - (a - r p[2]);
p[4] = p[3] - (a - r p[3]);
p[5] = p[4] - (a - r p[4]);
p[6] = p[5] - (a - r p[5]);
p[7] = p[6] - (a - r p[6]);
p[8] = p[7] - (a - r p[7]);

p[13] = p[8] - (a - r p[8]);
p[14] = p[13] - (a - r p[13]);
p[15] = p[14] - (a - r p[14]);
p[16] = p[15] - (a - r p[15]);
p[17] = p[16] - (a - r p[16]);
p[18] = p[17] - (a - r p[17]);
p[19] = p[18] - (a - r p[18]);
p[20] = p[19] - (a - r p[19]);

p[25] = p[20] - (a - r p[20]);
p[26] = p[25] - (a - r p[25]);
p[27] = p[26] - (a - r p[26]);
p[28] = p[27] - (a - r p[27]);
p[29] = p[28] - (a - r p[28]);
p[30] = p[29] - (a - r p[29]);
p[31] = p[30] - (a - r p[30]);
p[32] = p[31] - (a - r p[31]);

sol = Solve[p[32] == 0, a] ;
a = sol[[1, 1, 2]]
```

> 4298.12

Which matches the Hema calculation exactly.  The seasonal interest charges match too :-

```
r p[8]
```

> 168.326

```
r p[20]
```

> 85.0034

The main payment amount can also be calculated in one step using the [loan formula](http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html) given at the beginning of this answer like so :-

```
r = 0.03/12
s = 100000
n = 8
t = 3

monthly payment = (r*s)/(1 - (1 + r)^(-(n*t)))
```

> 4298.12

Comment: Great Answer, do you know what the Canadian or EU APR is

Comment: EU APR is the "effective annual rate" according to [Mortgage Interest Calculations in Canada](http://www.yorku.ca/amarshal/mortgage.htm).

Comment: hi Chris if I may bother you again, What if the compounding interest wasn't annually and changed to Monthly.

Comment: Hi. Once you have your interest as effective annual rate (EAR) any compounding interval produces the same result.  That's why it is used.  In the [mortgage example](http://www.yorku.ca/amarshal/mortgage.htm) `EAR = 0.0609; monthly = (1 + EAR)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.00493862`.  E.g. $100 for 2 years = `100*(1 + EAR)*(1 + EAR) = $112.551`, which is the same as $100 for 24 months = `100*(1 + monthly)^24 = $112.551`.

Comment: Sweet! Another Question, Does this formula take into account interest that still occurs during the months that have no principal?

Comment: Yes it does. You could imagine omitting the first 35 payments, then there would be just one term: `a(1 + i)^(-36/n) = s` or rather the familiar `a = s*(1 + i)^(36/n)`.

Comment: Hi chris, So the Linked question is the real applicable Question. I've tried to apply this to other scenarios, changing compounding frequency while payment staying the same. The values didn't quite match. I tried month/month But it didn't match with Tvalue, May I ask what you get.

Comment: Sorted it! (Working backwards from the spreadsheet helped.)

Comment: Hi Chris, going through this example again. I'm wondering what if the interest rate was not compounding annually, but instead it was semi annually? How would r = 0.03/12 change? Would I have to convert it to the effective annual rate? so instead of 0.03 it'll be (1 + 0.03/2)^2 ?

Comment: the link to the HEMA excel calculator is not working anymore. Any chance there is another copy available somewhere?